# Bootstrap with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

I update my Sf2 version to 2.6. And removed bundle for bootstrap. But now all my bootstrap styles are invalid. How I can understand from here the bootstrap only work with forms ?
[docs](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided explains you to set up Twig to use the Bootstrap form template. This template makes sure that all HTML generated by your forms will be formatted in a way that you can apply the bootstrap stylesheets to it. However, it does not include the Bootstrap stylesheets nor any javascript that you might want to use.

Make sure that you have Bootstrap installed (for instance with Bower) and that your stylesheets are included (probably using assetic) in your main templates. Or include the Bootstrap [CDN assets](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) in your main template.